# Proper release of OleCreateFromFile

Tags: c#, interop, ole

First of all. Thank you for any advice!

I am working on a OpenXML project and I need to convert files to *.bin format.

Everything works fine, but when I run test app Ive noticed that the number of GDI objects associated to application is increasing with every call to OleCreateFromFile(..)

Code:

```
        //init stuff
        storage = null;
        pOle = null;
        var result = OLE32.StgCreateStorageEx(oleOutputFileName,
            Convert.ToInt32(OLE32.STGM.STGM_READWRITE | OLE32.STGM.STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE | OLE32.STGM.STGM_CREATE | OLE32.STGM.STGM_TRANSACTED),
            Convert.ToInt32(OLE32.STGFMT.STGFMT_DOCFILE),
            0,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            ref OLE32.IID_IStorage,
            out storage
        );

        if (!HandleResult("StgCreateStorageEx", result))
            return false;

        var CLSID_NULL = Guid.Empty;
        msOleInterop.FORMATETC f = new msOleInterop.FORMATETC();          
        //Creates an embedded object from the contents of a named file. 
        string newInput = MultibyteToUnicodeNETOnly(_inputFileName, 1252);            
        result = OLE32.OleCreateFromFile(
            ref CLSID_NULL,
            newInput,
            ref OLE32.IID_IOleObject,
            (uint)msOleInterop.OLERENDER.OLERENDER_NONE,
            ref f,
            null,
            storage,
            out pOle
        );
```

... and releasing this way is not sufficient enough. GDI objects are still increasing (approx +2 every OleCreateFromFile call.

```
//Object release:    
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(storage);               
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pOle);
```

Definition for OleCreateFromFile

```
   #region OleCreateFromFile
    [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    public static extern int OleCreateFromFile([In] ref Guid rclsid,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpszFileName,
        [In] ref Guid riid, 
        uint renderopt,
        [In] ref FORMATETC pFormatEtc/*IntPtr pFormatEtc*/,
        IOleClientSite pClientSite, 
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IStorage pStg,
        out Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IOleObject ppvObj);        
    #endregion
```

Comment: Check if GC.Collect() has any effect.

Comment: Thank you. Ive tried that and it did not work. I did not even expected that to work to be honest.Gc.Collect() gets to be called anyway. I would just be calling it sooner. But There is a leak somewhere..

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(obj)
```

on everything you think is a reference to a com object